# LINQ performance when using nullable properties in select

Tags: performance, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an IEnumerable collection.
Using LINQ, I am populating the collection from a web service response.
Below is the sample I am using.

```
lookupData = from data in content["data"].Children()
             select new LookupData
             {
                 LookupKey = (data["data"]["key"]).ToString(),
                 LookupValue = (string)data["data"]["name"]
             };
```

I will be using the same code for a lot of similar responses which will return a key and value.

Now, I got a scenario when I needed an additional field from the service response for few of the responses(not for all). So, I created an "Optional" property in "LookUpData" class and used as below:

```
lookupData = from data in content["data"].Children()
             select new LookupData
             {
                 LookupKey = (data["data"]["key"]).ToString(),
                 LookupValue = (string)data["data"]["name"],
                 Optional = referenceConfig.Optional != null 
                            ? (data["data"]["optional"]).ToString()
                            : String.Empty
             };
```

The null check here is a performance issue. I do not want to use the below since I have other conditions and all together it will become a very big if else loop.

```
if(referenceConfig.Optional != null){

       lookupData = from data in content["data"].Children()
                     select new LookupData
                     {
                         LookupKey = (data["data"]["key"]).ToString(),
                         LookupValue = (string)data["data"]["name"],
                         Optional = (data["data"]["optional"]).ToString()
                     };
}
else{
       lookupData = from data in content["data"].Children()
                     select new LookupData
                     {
                         LookupKey = (data["data"]["key"]).ToString(),
                         LookupValue = (string)data["data"]["name"]
                     };
}
```

But I have at least 10 web server response with lots of data in each.

Comment: What is the type of `content["data"].Children()`? Does the indexer `data["data"]["optional"]` throw an exception if "optional" is not present?

Comment: `The null check here is a performance issue.` Seriously? And if so, how much of an impact and why?

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `referenceConfig.Optional` is available at compile time you can do

```
    #if OPTIONAL

    ...

    #else

    ...
```

If not - you can implement the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) i.e. have all of your `["data"][...]` properties always return a value(for instance string.Empty if the type is string) so you won't have check explicitly in the code.